# stripe graduated pricing with meter at a company level?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm having trouble creating a subscription plan for `number of seats` and `metered usage`.

each customer is a company (many seats).

Goal (plan A):

- charge $15 per user per month for the first 100 hours use.
- after 100 hours, surcharge $0.20 per hour use.

my problem is i need to set the "Unit" as # of seats and as # of hours used.

I'm not sure if stripe can do this?

#### Another way of viewing this:

Plan B:

- I can do plan A, but one a 1 customer = 1 user level.
- ie. create "graduated pricing", units are hours used.

Plan C:

- I can do plan A, but not have metered usage.
- ie. create "standard pricing", units are # of seats.

is there a way to combine both Plan B and C to make plan A?

Comment: I do not think what you described above is directly supported. However, [this][1] might be the closest to what you're looking for. You can create a base fee for $15, then use metered [pricing][2] after 100 hours. Can you try this?    


  [1]: https://stripe.com/docs/products-prices/pricing-models#flat-rate-per-seat
  [2]: https://stripe.com/docs/products-prices/pricing-models#model-usage-based-pricing-on-stripe